# Can't launch web platform installer

Tags: windows-server-2008, internet-explorer, web-platform-installer

I need to install url-rewrite module (windows server 2008) - while extension starts setup it tries to launch web platform installer- get error:

**Unable download the product list from. Check your network connection and ....**

I have two installed browsers - IE and FireFox.

In IE there is a proxy which I tried to disable but without success - every time it restores (FireFox allows me to disable proxy). Can the reason for the platform installer failure be in IE settings?

Comment: I'd use the standalone installer instead.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7435